# ScrollView only scroll when I change the rotation of Simulator in ios

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, xamarin.ios

I have spend 1 hour but till not find the solution why this happen.

I am setting `ContentView` inside my `ScrollView` and `ContentView` have a `Button` at the End. But When I run the project. The ScrollView not scroll. But When I rotate the Simulator and Again check then it's work.

What is happening can anyone tell me why this happening.

**Code :**

```
public override void ViewDidLayoutSubviews()
        {
            base.ViewDidLayoutSubviews();

            AutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false;
            scrollView.ContentSize = ContainerView.Bounds.Size;
            scrollView.LayoutIfNeeded();


        }
```

I am new to iOS and Xamarin.

Any help be Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with Xamarin, but after setting contentSize to its superview bounds.size it shouldn't be scrolling at all. The thing is, it is only scrolling when it need to and you set its size exactly the same, as it is already.

So, if I got it correctly, and **ContainerView** is the superview of scrollView and **ContentView** is the subview of it, you have to use something like

```
scrollView.ContentSize = ContentView.Bounds.Size;
```

Comment: could you check your bounds values? superview, scrollView, contentView?

also, try to remove that row of code at all, because it doesn't make sense now